# R fedora package .lme4 error on install RcppEigen.h missing

Tags: r, fedora-23

Attempts to install package lme4 result in:

```
cpp -o external.o
In file included from external.cpp:8:0:
predModule.h:12:23: fatal error: RcppEigen.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:139: recipe for target 'external.o' failed
make: *** [external.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lme4’
```

The system is Fedora Core 23
R is 3.3.1
Searches do not produce references to resolve the RccpEigen reference. Is there a workaround.

Comment: Install [RcppEigen](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppEigen)

Comment: how did you attempt to install?  Normally `RcppEigen` dependency would automatically get installed as part of the process ...

Comment: From the R command like - install.packages("lme4")